# How isolate IO pins of Arduino and PSU output?

Tags: power-supply, arduino, isolation, backup

[image: Sorry for my entry level drawing]

I will start by saying that I am a beginner of electronics and I don't have much experience hence I am making this post asking for advice from more experienced peopled than me.

Now that I have lowered the expectations :), let me present my situation:

I have a 12 V PSU with 12 V 7 Ah SLA battery backup that has two sets of 13.8 V outputs, one of them goes into a board with multiple fuses from where I will be powering my electronics. Presented at the beginning of my drawing, I will call output1 and output2, which are two fused output I am interested of using.

Afterwards I have a simple PIR sensor which gets 12 V DC for power, and outputs a signal which must be interpreted by an Arduino MCU board. Nothing fancy so far, I expressed that fact that I will give power for the sensor from output1 and power to Arduino from output2. The output of the sensor goes into a digital input pin on Arduino.

Now I want to make this setup proof to any external interventions of sabotage as an example would be to apply an overvoltage maybe even 230 ac power to any wires that goes into that sensor and try to fry/affect the Arduino input pin/PSU which is also powering the Arduino.

For that I have into consideration to use some sort of device that will just interrupt the wiring in case of not normal operation or even fry itself protecting the other components.

What I need is:

A device which will protect the sensor output line which get received by Arduino IO pins and not fry them. For that I considered an optocoupler.
Considerations; an optocoupler would work for a digital high/low signal that comes from the sensor, on one side sensor high pin and sensor GND / on the other side Arduino 5 V and input pin (with corresponding resistors and wiring but that's not my main subject here).

In case of sabotage for that output line I suppose this will do but what if I want to read analog values instead of digital? This optocoupler is only closing a circuit when it have voltage on the transmitter led side letting the 5 V of the Arduino flow into the Digital input pin.

For the power side, I have purposely powered the sensor/Arduino from two different outputs to express that I need some sort of protection on the output1 which is powering sensors, and in case there will be an attempt of sabotage on the sensor ~12v power wires, the device must interrupt the power and protect the PSU itself also the other components powered from the same PSU but different outputs and keep them running.

For isolation I considered a 12 V DC-DC transformer which only creates a galvanic isolation between sides but has nothing to do with overvoltage protection.

On same topic I would want to ask if transistors can act as separators in case of overvoltage between collector-emitter and just fry if exceeded max voltage rating.

I am looking forward for any advise, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it is not a forum, so I have removed greetings and thanks (show thanks by voting on and accepting answers). I also edited for capitalization and spelling.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide some circuits, that contain examples of "sabotage". To protect the output of a supply is very different from protecting an MCU input.

Comment: Hy, i want to do both you mentioned, protect all the wires that come to the sensor, 12v  power wires wich come from the psu output1  and output of the sensor wich goes to the arduino input. For arduino side i was informed to use an ADC or voltage to frequency converter for analog signals and pass that signal trough an optocoupler. For psu side i am considering such device but i am still wondering if it will protect the psu side  isolated Dc/DC converter traco

Comment: the sabotage can be whatever you think of hurting the devices that sit at the other side of the sensor's wires, for example applying high voltages like 230v AC to power wires or signal output of sensor. Also i am looking forward to do such wiring that can't disable the reading of the pir module in any case so that it won't become irresponsible and not detects anymore or be able to transmit to the arduino.

Comment: for example, if the output is normal high, what if someone just applies 5v from a battery to the signal wire and cut the incoming signal from the sensor hence bypassing it.